# Error in archiving project xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

My application is properly working on iPad and simulator. It doesn't show any error and builds successfully.

**Problem**: When I am archiving my project it's giving me this error.

```
/Users/synapse/Desktop/myProject/myProject_Prefix.pch:15:13: fatal error: 'BoxSDK/BoxSDK.h' file not found
#import <BoxSDK/BoxSDK.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
Command /Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" to your header search path, this saves my life.

Answer (score 1):

(As of Xcode 5.1)

When the subproject is built by XCode, the subproject header files are copied into the build directory. When archiving, it seems that this copy destination directory is not added to the header/include search path. You'll want to go to your Build Settings and add

```
$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include
```

to the "Header Search Paths" for the scheme that you use for archiving.

If you're not sure which scheme is used for archiving, go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Schemes and look for Archive in the left column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this link may help you : [Here](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/issues/14)

In the framework and static library header files, do angle bracket import as :

```
#import <BoxCocoaSDK/BoxSDKConstants.h>

#import <BoxCocoaSDK/BoxLog.h>

#import <BoxCocoaSDK/BoxSDKErrors.h>
```

and you need to add the include directory to your HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS.

Comment: how can i set header search path?

Comment: You can set it in build settings.

Comment: what should i add in that field?